# accessing viewControllers with In-app purchases from 2 different view controllers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Did any of you guys ever tried implementing IAP store view controller in app that is reachable from 2 different view controllers? I would really appreciate if anyone could share such experience.

I am trying to make StoreViewController (you can buy in-app purchases in it) reachable from 2 different view controllers. This image shows what I mean:

[image]

Therefore both the black and blue VC implement `SKProductsRequestDelegate` method.

This is the code from 1, but it is identical in 2:

```
        let productID1 = "id1"
            let productID2 = "id2"
            let productID3 = "id3"
            let productID4 = "id4"

            var product1 : SKProduct?
            var product2 : SKProduct?
            var product3 : SKProduct?
            var product4 : SKProduct?

    /////// THIS BUTTON TAKES USER TO STORE
    @IBAction goToStore(){
    getProductInfo()
    }
        func getProductInfo(){
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set([productID1,productID2,productID3,productID4]))
                request.delegate = self
                request.start()
                print("looking for IAP")
            }else{
                print("make IAP available in Settings")
            }
        }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

            let products = response.products
            if products.count != 0{
                for product in products{
                    switch product.productIdentifier{
                    case "id1":
                        product1 = product
                        break
                    case "id2":
                        product2 = product
                        break
                    case "id3":
                        product3 = product
                        break
                    case "id4":
                        product4 = product
                        break

                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
                print("I do have products")
                performAnimation()

                //            }

            }else{
                print("product not found")
            }
            let invalidProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
            for productk in invalidProducts{
                print("Pr not found \(productk)")
            }
        }

    func performAnimation(){

     let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let storeViewController = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoreViewController") as! StoreViewController
     storeViewController.product1 = self.product1
     storeViewController.product2 = self.product2
     storeViewController.product3 = self.product3
     storeViewController.product4 = self.product4

       self.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)})

                })
            }
```

////////////////////Code in storeViewController

```
            let productID1 = "id1"
            let productID2 = "id2"
            let productID3 = "id3"
            let productID4 = "id4"
            var product1 : SKProduct?
            var product2 : SKProduct?
            var product3 : SKProduct?
            var product4 : SKProduct?

 viewDidLoad(){
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }
//// PRESSED WHEN USER WANTS TO BUY ITEMS
@IBAction func buyButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let items = itemsToBuy.count
    if items > 0{
        switch items{
        case 1:
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product1!)
             print("description \(payment.description), identifier: \(payment.productIdentifier), data: \(payment.requestData)")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment) ///////// ERROR HERE

        case 2:
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product2!)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

        case 3:
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product3!)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

        case 4:
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product4!)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

        default:
            break
        }


    }

}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions{
        switch transaction.transactionState{
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
            self.buyItems()
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("bought")
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("error not bought")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I go to store from VC1, make and make a purchase succesfully. Than I go to store from VC2 (or vice versa) and I ger an error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)`  in switch statement.

[image]

This error has not occurred when store was accessible only from one VC and not from both of them. Also, if I make multiple payments solely from one VC it works fine. What could be the reason? Is there only one viewController capable of implementing `SKProductsRequestDelegate` methods?

EDIT:// added a print statement just before `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)` line. The result of both purchases (1. successful, 2. unsuccesful) is

```
 description <SKPayment: 0x174204720>, identifier: id1, data: nil
```

and

```
 description <SKPayment: 0x17001e1b0>, identifier: id1, data: nil
```

Comment: Try to log your `payment` object of line: `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)`

Comment: I added a print statement. see edit

Comment: You can see that data is nil for that product. Try to find why you are getting data of SKPayment nil..

Comment: no, check the docs. It must be nil https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPayment/requestData

Comment: Guessing here, but i think that if on the viewWillDisappear of the STORE viewController you'll do a removeTransactionObserver of self, it will no longer crash when you open the page again. let me know if it worked.

Comment: that worked! thank you so much. MIght just staty another bounty so I can reward you. Please write an answer below